# htaccess for redirect to SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For the past few hours (days) I have been having some trouble redirecting a
page to SSL.

My setup is as follows: I have the following .htaccess for an e-commerce site
on Apache 2.2.16 on Debian (all required mods enabled)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|products|img|theme\.php|checkout\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

all requests are passed to index.php which acts as my controller and includes
other .php files as necessary.

I now want to use HTTPS for the checkout process which is a php script
cleverly called checkout.php

I thought it would be as easy as changing my .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_URI} checkout\.php
RewriteRule ^checkout.php?/$1 https://localhost/shop/checkout.php?/$1 [L,R]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|products|img|theme\.php|checkout\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

so that checkout.php is not processed by index.php.
Apparently it is not that simple. I could probably do it by using a hardcoded 
https link to checkout but I would prefer to do it with mod_rewrite.
If anyone can share some insight into
this it would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of checking %{SERVER_PORT} try checking %{HTTPS}

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems.  First, the pattern in your first RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^checkout.php?/$1   https://localhost/shop/checkout.php?/$1 [L,R]
```

is written incorrectly.  `$1` isn't meaningful there (it's a capture result, but no capture has happened yet), and also the query string (part of the request after the `?`) isn't part of what's matched, as the [RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) says.

Second, I think you meant to use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `SERVER_URI`.

So I think you want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout\.php
RewriteRule .* https://localhost/shop/checkout.php [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|products|img|theme\.php|checkout\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

A few notes:

- You don't need to match or add back in the query string in the first RewriteRule; mod_rewrite will automatically add it back in.
- It's conventional to test `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` instead of 
  `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443`, as @Jon Lin suggests.
- You may want to add the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) in your second RewriteRule.